# Eclipse IDE dead code warning with two conditions — how to suppress it?

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

In the code example below, the code block within the if statement is marked as dead code by Eclipse. This is expected because the code is indeed unreachable,  however these final properties are intended to serve as a configuration in my actual codebase and may be edited. I can't get suppresswarnings to work, though.

I've tried adding a `@suppresswarnings` annotation before the `static` block, before the `if` block, and before the `class` declaration, but none of these have worked. The strange part is that if there is only one condition in the `if` statement, the code is not marked as dead code (e.g. if SOME_OTHER_CONDITION is removed).

```
public class Example {
    private static final boolean ENABLED = false;
    private static final boolean SOME_OTHER_CONDITION = false;

    static {
        if (ENABLED && SOME_OTHER_CONDITION) {
            System.out.println("Enabled!");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can do to ignore these warnings *without* editing preference or project settings? Perhaps there is a way to restructure the code to avoid it?

Comment: You have made both **constants** `false` but you check both for `true`, that is a pretty good reason to call the line in the body of the `if` statement *dead*... Since the condition will never resolve to `true`, the code will never be reached. To get rid of it, remove the `final` modifyer. This will be helpful if you want to change their values later on, too.

Comment: But why is it not dead code if there is only constant in the if statement? E.g. `if (ENABLED)`

Comment: That's a good question... I'll check it out... in Eclipse...

Comment: Obviously, Eclipse doesn't do the check for dead code if only one variable or constant is involved (tried with `||` and it also warns). Why is it like that? But besides, why do you want constants to be `false` and then check for their value?

Comment: I have an abstract `Config` class which contains some static variables. The constant  is supposed to remain the same within a program execution (which is why it is final), but it may be changed between two executions.

Comment: Considering your remark, that one condition is not marked, what about: `if (ENABLED) if (SOME_OTHER_CONDITION) {
`

Comment: That indeed solves it. It's a bit hacky, but I guess that's fine.

Comment: Consider moving the values to a file to be read at run-time which allows behavior to change without having to change and recompile the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid this warning if you nest the `if` statements like this:

```
public class Example {

private static final boolean ENABLED = false;
private static final boolean SOME_OTHER_CONDITION = false;

    static {
        if (SOME_OTHER_CONDITION) {
            if (ENABLED) {
                System.out.println("Enabled!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` above the class declaration, like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Example {

    private static final boolean ENABLED = false;
    private static final boolean SOME_OTHER_CONDITION = false;

    static {
        if (ENABLED && SOME_OTHER_CONDITION) {
            System.out.println("Enabled!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: A red underline appears below `static` with the following error: Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeader

Comment: @Skere It won't if you apply it above the class declaration.

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` would be sufficient and not suppress all warnings.

Comment: @howlger Yes, that is better.